# Promises with http.get node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Im am doing nodeschool exercises. The

> This problem is the same as the previous problem (HTTP COLLECT) in
> that you need to use http.get(). However, this time you will be
> provided with three URLs as the first three command-line arguments.
>
> You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the
> URLs and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print out
> the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch is
> that you must print them out in the same order as the URLs are
> provided to you as command-line arguments.

in other words , i am to register 3 http.get request , and print data recieved from it in order.

I am trying to do it with promises = another get request wont be called untill the first on didnt end.

My code looks like this:

```
var http=require("http");
var collect=[];
var dat=[];
for( var i = 2 ; i < process.argv.length;i++){
    collect.push(process.argv[i]);
}

function chainIt(array,callback){
    return array.reduce(function(promise,item){
        return promise.then(function(){
            return callback(item)
        })
    },Promise.resolve())
}

function getIt(item){
    return http.get(item,function(response){
        response.on("data",function(data){
                dat.push(data);
        })
        
    })
}


chainIt(collett,function(item){
    return getIt(item)
    })
}).then(function(){
    collect.forEach(function(x){
            console.log(x);
    })
    
})
```

But I actually print no data. Thus, I fail the exercise.

I do not see any bug here. I am just starting with promises and node. Where is the mistake?

Comment: `http.get` does not return a promise (it uses the callback-style syntax), meaning your promise chaining will not wait for the previous `http.get` to complete. So your `console.log` statement at the end will be called immediately, rather than waiting for the `http.get` calls to complete.

Answer (score 8):

For educational purposes, I recently wrote a wrapper for the `http` and `https` modules that uses native `Promise`s. That said, I recommend using a library, such a [`request`](https://github.com/request/request); that makes things simpler, has unit test coverage, as is maintained by the open source community. Also, my wrapper does a naive string concatenation with the response chunks, which I'm not convinced is the most performant way of building up the response body.

**FYI**: this requires Node.js 4 or above, although the methodology is pretty much the same in Node 0.x.x.

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

module.exports = {
    get(url) {
        return this._makeRequest('GET', url);
    },

    _makeRequest(method, urlString, options) {

        // create a new Promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            /* Node's URL library allows us to create a
             * URL object from our request string, so we can build
             * our request for http.get */
            const parsedUrl = url.parse(urlString);

            const requestOptions = this._createOptions(method, parsedUrl);
            const request = http.get(requestOptions, res => this._onResponse(res, resolve, reject));

            /* if there's an error, then reject the Promise
             * (can be handled with Promise.prototype.catch) */
            request.on('error', reject);

            request.end();
        });
    },

    // the options that are required by http.get
    _createOptions(method, url) {
        return  requestOptions = {
            hostname: url.hostname,
            path: url.path,
            port: url.port,
            method
        };
    },

    /* once http.get returns a response, build it and 
     * resolve or reject the Promise */
    _onResponse(response, resolve, reject) {
        const hasResponseFailed = response.status >= 400;
        var responseBody = '';

        if (hasResponseFailed) {
            reject(`Request to ${response.url} failed with HTTP ${response.status}`);
        }

        /* the response stream's (an instance of Stream) current data. See:
         * https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data */
        response.on('data', chunk => responseBody += chunk.toString());

        // once all the data has been read, resolve the Promise 
        response.on('end', () => resolve(responseBody));
    }
};
```

**EDIT:** I only just realised you're new to `Promise`s. Here's an example of how to use this wrapper:

```
'use strict';

const httpService = require('./httpService'); // the above wrapper

// get one URL
httpService.get('https://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes').then(function gotData(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// get multiple URLs
const urls = [
    'https://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes',
    'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random'
];

/* map the URLs to Promises. This will actually start the
 * requests, but Promise.prototype.then is always called,
 * even if the operation has resolved */
const promises = urls.map(url => httpService.get(url));

Promise.all(promises).then(function gotData(responses) {
    /* responses is an array containing the result of each
     * Promise. This is ordered by the order of the URLs in the
     * urls array */

    const swansonQuote = responses[0];
    const chuckNorrisQuote = responses[1];

    console.log(swansonQuote);
    console.log(chuckNorrisQuote);
});
```

Comment: If I use https.get().then, it tells me that https.get is not a .then function. I can't understand how to fetch a url using https.get by promises. Can you help in that please ?

Comment: @Manahil That's because at present, most, if not all, asynchronous methods provided by Node.js are callback-driven and don't return `Promise`s. Rather than using the `https` module directly, update the `httpService` itself to use `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: *UPD* the `request` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)

Answer (score 4):

Using Promise.all is the most efficient solution for this. You could also use async/await like below to solve this.

```
const http = require('http');
const bl = require('bl');

async function httpGet(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(url, response => {
            response.setEncoding('utf8');
            response.pipe(bl((err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(data.toString());
            }));
        });
    });
}

async function main() {

   const data1 = await httpGet(process.argv[2]);
   const data2 = await httpGet(process.argv[3]);
   const data3 = await httpGet(process.argv[4]);
   console.log(data1);
   console.log(data2);
   console.log(data3);
}
main();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this exercise was meant to be solved with promises. I found my old exercice folder, this is how I did it without promises or extra libraries:

```
var http = require('http');
var urls = process.argv.slice(2);

// counts the number of requests done
var done = 0;
// stores the requests result
var result = [];

// this will be called by each http.get and they will provide their index
function callback(index, data) {
  result[index] = data;
  done++;
  // all requests are done, log everything
  if (done == urls.length) {
    result.forEach(console.log);
  }
}

function processUrl(url, index) {
  var finalData = '';
  http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      finalData += data;
    });
    response.on('error', console.error);
    response.on('end', function() {
      // console.log(finalData);
      callback(index, finalData);
    })
  });
}

urls.forEach(processUrl);
```

Don't worry, you'll have enough promises to play with in the `promise-it-wont-hurt` workshop.

Comment: Are other courses worth it too? I have heard only reviews about their learnyounode ... i thought this would be great chance to practice promises >X

Comment: @Johnyb Yes, there are few other interesting workshops I recommend (after finishing *learnyounode*): *Functional Javascript*, *Async You*, *LololoDash*, *Promise It Won't Hurt* (it's better to do them in this order), *stream-adventure* (streams are powerful and pretty common nodejs tool). *Scope Chains & Closures* if you're not familiar with closures.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party here :)

Unfortunately none of the answers here uses the builtin `util` module in node.

Here is how to promisify `http.get` using `util` module and it is working correctly with typescript:

```
import util from "util";
const httpGetPromisified = util.promisify(
  (url: string, cb: (err: any, result: IncomingMessage) => void) =>
    http.get(url, (res) => cb(null, res))
);

// with promise.then
httpGetPromisified("http://www.google.com").then((res) => {
  // res here has type http.IncomingMessage
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});

// with async/await
const res = await httpGetPromisified("http://www.google.com");
console.log(res.statusCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution after going through this thread:

```
var http = require('http');
var bl   = require('bl') 

promises = [
    promiseLoad(process.argv[2]),
    promiseLoad(process.argv[3]),
    promiseLoad(process.argv[4])
];

Promise.all(promises).then(function(res) {

  for(i=0; i<promises.length; i++) {
    console.log(res[i]);
  }
});

function promiseLoad(url) {
  var body = '';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url, function (response) { 
    response.setEncoding('utf8'); 
       response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {  
         resolve(data.toString())
       }))  
     })
  });
}
```

Here's the official solution in case you want to compare notes:

```
 var http = require('http')  
 var bl = require('bl')  
 var results = []  
 var count = 0  

 function printResults () {  
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
     console.log(results[i])  
   }  
 }  

 function httpGet (index) {  
   http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {  
     response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {  
       if (err) {  
         return console.error(err)  
       }  

       results[index] = data.toString()  
       count++  

       if (count === 3) {  
         printResults()  
       }  
     }))  
   })  
 }  

 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
   httpGet(i)  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');

const urls = process.argv.slice(2);
let callCount = 0;

const cb =  (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    rawData += chunk.toString();
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    callCount += 1;
    console.log(rawData);
    if (callCount < urls.length) {
      getData(urls[callCount]);
    }
  });
  res.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};


const getData = (url) => {
   http.get(url, cb);
};

getData(urls[callCount]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```js
async myFunc = function {
    let url = 'http://your.data/file';
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var data = '';
        https.get(url, res => {
            res.on('data', chunk => { data += chunk }) 
            res.on('end', () => {
               resolve(data);
            })
        }) 
    });

    let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves
    doStuffWithResult(result);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the method is by using 'Q' library.

First create function that will hit URL and return promise

```
var Q = require('q);
function getIt(item){
 return http.get(item,function(response){

       return Q.resolve(response); // Return response
         OR
       return Q.resolve(error);    // Return error

     })
  })
}



var urls = ['url1','url2','url3']; // list of urls

Q.spread(urls.map(getIt))
 .then(function(res1,res2,res3){ 

    // res1 is response for url1 and on
    //Once all calls are finished you will get results here
 });
```

Comment: Seeing ops code, i think he wants to do it in basic promise style withou using external modules. Also he mentioned he is starting with promises so it could confuse him