# How to wait for multiple API calls to reutrn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, asynchronous

I have an array of APIs to query. For example `var urls = ['example.org?x=1', 'example.org?x=2,3']` How can I have ReactJS wait for all the responses (which are JSON) to come back before responding to the client?

I've tried a modification @Shanoor's answer from [Promises with http.get node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182752/promises-with-http-get-node-js) but the result to the client is empty (`""`).

```
var http = require('http');
var urls = ['example.org', 'example2.org', '...'];

var done = 0;
var result = [];

function callback(index, data) {
  result[index] = data;
  done++;
  if (done == urls.length) {
    result.forEach(console.log);
    //I tried using the resp object here to return result[] but the data seemed corrupt 
  }
}

function processUrl(url, index) {
  var finalData = '';
  http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      finalData += data;
    });
    response.on('error', console.error);
    response.on('end', function() {
      callback(index, finalData);
    })
  });
}

app.get("/api/blah", (resp) => {
  urls.forEach(processUrl);
  //resp(result); this would result in an empty response
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promise to do that, should be something like

```
function processUrl(url, index) {
  var finalData = '';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, function(response) {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      response.on('data', function(data) {
        finalData += data;
      });
      response.on('error', reject);
      response.on('end', function() {
        resolve(finalData);
      })
    });
  })
}

app.get("/api/blah", (resp) => {
  Promise.all(urls.map(processUrl)).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```

Note that I didn't checked if the code is working, so please read more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method

Comment: This is because the first argument was an index. see the code again, I edited it to parse only the `finalData` argument, no need for index