# async / await version of https.get vs promise version vs callback version in asynchronous JavaScript programming

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, callback

Why this async/await version of asynchronous program in JS doesn't give any output?

**async-await version:**

```
const https = require('https');

async function getDataFromServer() {
  try {
    const response = await https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    let data = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

getDataFromServer();
```

whereas other two versions work?

**callback version:**

```
const https = require('https');

function getDataFromServer(callback) {
  https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', (response) => {
    let data = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      callback(data);
    });
  }).on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

getDataFromServer((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

**promise version:**

```
const https = require('https');

function getDataFromServer() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', (response) => {
      let data = '';
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    }).on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

getDataFromServer().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Thank you.

I tried three versions of simple asynchronous programming examples in JavaScript (with callback, promise, and async-await), but I cannot figure out why the async/await version cannot give the same result as the other two versions? I.e., nothing appears in console window.

Comment: Using `await` only really makes sense if the thing to the right hand side of it is a thenable (ie: a Promise). Does `https.get()` return a Promise?

Comment: `https.get` does not return a `Promise`, so you can't truly await it.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182752/promises-with-http-get-node-js) is relevant. I don't think `https.get()` returns Promise instances.

Comment: `response` from you async/await version is an instance of `ClientRequest` and `response` from the callback is an instance of `IncomingMessage`. They are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Why this async/await version of asynchronous program in JS doesn't give any output?

Because you're just using `https.get()` wrong.  That function REQUIRES a callback in order to get a response back.  It does not support promises in any way.

Thus, when you do this:

```
const response = await https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
```

That `await` isn't doing anything useful because `https.get()` does not return a promise - instead it returns a `http.ClientRequest` object that you would write to if it was a POST or some other type of request that you need to write a body with.  `await` is ONLY useful when awaiting a promise that resolves to the value you want.  So, since you don't pass a callback, you never get the response object and you are, instead, attaching your event handlers to the request object which never emits a `data` or `end` event and thus "nothing" seems to happen.  In reality, the request is sent, but you don't have the right listeners to get the response.

Instead, you have to get the `response` object by passing a callback function just like you do in your other two examples.

---

Note: `https.get()` is a pretty low level API that doesn't inherently support promises.  For code that just wants to send a request and get the whole response using promises, it will save you code to use a higher level API that has built-in promise support.  Popular options are:

```
fetch()
got()
axios()
```

As of nodejs v18, the same implementation of `fetch()` as used in browsers is now present in nodejs:

```
async function getDataFromServer() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    const results = await response.json();
    console.log(results);
}

getDataFromServer().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

My personal favorite is the [got() library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) (I just like the programming interface and it is has a rich feature set).

```
const got = require('got');

async function getDataFromServer() {
    const result = await got('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').json();
    console.log(result);
}

getDataFromServer().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using nodejs [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsgetoptions-callback) module to fetch the data. It support callback only.

To make into async/await, call your promise version this way

```
const https = require('https');

function getDataFromServer() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', (response) => {
        let data = '';
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
          resolve(data);
        });
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

//wrap your promise based version as async call
async function getDataFromServerAsync() {
  // return the response
  return await getDataFromServer();
}

//call the async function
getDataFromServerAsync().then((resp) => {
  console.log('Response received: ', resp);
});
```

Comment: There is no point to your `getDataFromServerAsync()` function.  It's the same as just calling `getDataFromServer()` directly.  Both return a promise that resolves to the same value.