# Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'

Tags: node.js, express, http, httprequest

i have some error. I want to show a data from api. This is a api:
[Click Here](http://dev3.dansmultipro.co.id/api/recruitment/positions.json).

This is my request to get that data:

```
import Http from "http";

var positions = await Http.get(
    "http://dev3.dansmultipro.co.id/api/recruitment/positions.json"
);
var position = JSON.stringify(positions);
console.log(position);
```

And this is my error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at get (E:\Project Freelance\Github-Job\server2\src\controllers\jobs.controller.js:17:33)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

I've try to do this with CircularJSON:

```
import Http from "http";
import CircularJSON from "circular-json";

var positions = await Http.get(
    "http://dev3.dansmultipro.co.id/api/recruitment/positions.json"
);
var position = CircularJSON.stringify(positions);
var data = JSON.parse(position);
console.log(data.res);
```

And the response is null. What's wrong and what i supposed to do?

Comment: What is your goal? `http.get()` returns a `ClientRequest` object, which among other things has properties that aren't serializable. What are you trying to serialize?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things wrong with this code.

First, this statement:

```
var positions = await Http.get(
    "http://dev3.dansmultipro.co.id/api/recruitment/positions.json"
);
```

does not do what you think it does.  First off `http.get()` does not return a promise.  It returns a request object.  One would use that request object to write the body of a request (for methods like POST or PUT).  It does not return the response to that http request.

Second, since it doesn't return a promise, the `await` here is pointless.

Third, the ONLY way to get the response object from `http.get()` is to pass it a callback.  Thus, your code does NOT get the response at all.

So, what you're trying to JSON serialize is a request object which contains a native object (the TCP socket) and is not serializable in JSON and there's no reason to do so either since even if it was serialized it can't be used again when its unserialized.  The socket itself is not serializable.

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839508/async-await-version-of-https-get-vs-promise-version-vs-callback-version-in-asy/75839615#75839615) to see how you should be using `http.get()` and what your options are if you want to use a promise.  Here's a simple example for getting JSON.  More options are show in that other answer.

```
function httpGetJSON(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         http.get(url, response => {
             let result = "";
             response.on('data', data => {
                  result += data.toString();
             }).on('end', () => {
                  try {
                      const obj = JSON.parse(result);
                      resolve(obj);
                  } catch (e) {
                      reject(e);
                  }
             }).on('error', reject);
         });
    });
}
```